# Code works fine, but Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC still pops up

Tags: c#, excel, openxml, excel-interop

I've been trying to figure out why the <'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in Student.dll but was not handled in user code > keeps popping up even though the code works fine. It did copy from one of the excel worksheet and paste it to the other one. 
Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
//The existing template
string templatePath = @"C:\Users\Field\Employee.xlsx";

//The destination excel sheet 
string destPath = @"C:\Users\Field\Students" + TextBox2.Text + "" 
                  + DateTime.Now.ToString("MM_dd_yyyy_hh_mm_ss") + ".xlsx";

File.Copy(templatePath, destPath);

//Opening the second worksheet and pasting it
var destxlApp = new Excel.Application();
var destworkBook = destxlApp.Workbooks.Open(destPath, 0, false);
var destworkSheet = new Excel.Worksheet();
var destrange = destworkSheet.Cells[1, 1];
destrange.Select();

destxlApp.Application.DisplayAlerts = false;
destworkBook.Close(true, null, null);
destxlApp.Quit();
```

Comment: What is the stacktrace? What line could be giving this issue?

Comment: This line --> var destworkBook = destxlApp.Workbooks.Open(destPath, 0, false);

Comment: Is it possible you also have the file open in Excel at the time?  You are opening it for read/write, which may be causing a problem if the file is open elsewhere.

Comment: @JohnKoerner I made sure the Excel file was not open before doing anything else, but the Exception still pops up when I execute the file

Comment: Please wrap your code in a try-catch block, put a breakpoint in the catch block (or simply [enable your debugger to break on any COM exception](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d14azbfh(v=vs.120).aspx)) and post the stacktrace and type of the exception.

Comment: @DirkVollmar It did work after that , Thank you!